# Returning array indices for positive array values - The array being part of a Tuple

Tags: c#, arrays, find, tuples

I have the following list containing a tuple:

```
List<Tuple<int, int[]>> someInfo = new List<Tuple<int, int[]>>();
```

Now, considering my tuple has been populated with reasonable values, how could I extract all the indices corresponding to values greater than 0 within my int[]?

As an example, say the int[] from my tuple has been initialised as such:

```
int[] values = new int[] { -5, 5, 100, -52, 6 };
```

Then the list of returned indices for all positive values (ie. 5, 100 and 6) in this particular Tuple should be: 1, 2 and 4 (0 based indexing).
We then need to do that for all the Tuples from the List "someInfo ".
The result can be extracted into a List of int[].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Linq to select both the value and the index, then filter out items whose value doesn't meet your filter criteria, and return the indexes:

```
List<Tuple<int, int[]>> someInfo = new List<Tuple<int, int[]>>
{
    new Tuple<int, int[]>(1, new[] {0, -1, -2, -3, -4}),
    new Tuple<int, int[]>(1, new[] {-5, 5, 100, -52, 5}),
    new Tuple<int, int[]>(1, new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5})
};

List<int[]> positiveValueIndices = someInfo
    .Select(tuple => tuple.Item2
        .Select((value, index) => new {value, index})
        .Where(item => item.value > 0)
        .Select(item => item.index)
        .ToArray())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, there is an extra layer, the Tuple is part of a list.

Comment: So then what type of result are you looking for? An `int[]` will likely have duplicate values since it would contain the indices from all the tuples in your list, and you would not know which tuple they belonged to (i.e. if you have three tuples in a list and only the first and third tuples had positive values, both of which were at `.Item2[0]`, then the resulting array would contain `{0, 0}`. Do you want a `List<int[]>` instead?

Comment: Yes, the result can be extracted into a List<int[]>, so that results from each Tuple do not get mixed up. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer. It would be more helpful if the question provided sample data in the form of a `List<Tuple<int, int[]>>` instead of just an `int[]`, though. :)

Comment: Beautiful, thanks! I'll give you a +1 when my reputation allows :-)

Answer (score 0):

To get the indices for single array, you can use this:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, values.Length).Where(i => values[i] >= 0)
```

To get indices for the whole list:

```
someInfo.Select(tuple => Enumerable.Range(0, tuple.Item2.Length).Where(i => tuple.Item2[i] >= 0).ToArray()).ToList()
```

Comment: `Select` has an overload that includes the index, so that `Enumerable.Range` hack is not needed.